# Elastic Beanstalk doesn't accept my changes to WSGIPath

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, wsgi

I have an app where I want to run it from aws_wsgi.py instead of application.py, as there are several different entry points depending on where we are hosting it. For this reason, I would like to be able to change the WSGIPath variable to point to the correct location.

This, in an .ebextensions .config file, does not work:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace:    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python"
    option_name:  WSGIPath
    value:        "/opt/python/current/app/aws_wsgi.py"
```

The environment attempts to use 'application.py' despite the above lines. No error appears to be emitted. Other parts of that same config file work perfectly, such as `packages` commands to get the system to install some yum packages. I can confirm the config files are getting uploaded in the logs:

```
INFO: Creating new application version using project code
WARNING: You have uncommitted changes.
INFO: Getting version label from git with git-describe
Creating application version archive "0_3_0-507-ga36f".
INFO: creating zip using git archive HEAD
INFO: git archive output: .ebextensions/
.ebextensions/01-weave_server_eb.config
.ebextensions/02-weave_server_eb_lxml_dependencies.config
.ebextensions/03-weave_server_eb_nltk_data.config
.ebextensions/04-weave_server_eb_entity_data.config
.ebextensions/05-weave_server_eb_geography_data.config
.gitattributes
.gitignore
```

...etc.

We run with a saved configuration, i.e. via `eb create --cfg Live`, and in the dashboard, that configuration shows that WSGIPath is "application.py". But there is nowhere to change that value in the dashboard. It seems like it is a built-in value that overrides the data we send with the above config file.

I tried adding it as an environment variable via the dashboard, but that goes in the `aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment` namespace and does not affect how the application is started up in the first place. (I checked this by using `eb config` to download the configuration.)

Maybe I could add a section in the file retrieved by `eb config`, but I heard that doing that will start to override .ebextensions files, and I have several important commands in my .ebextensions files that I need to continue using. (But see the comment below.) It's not clear from the documentation how .ebextensions data translates to and compares with config files used by eb config but the .ebextensions files are well-documented and reasonably convenient so I'd rather not break those if possible!

If I retrieve the configuration on the server via `eb config get Live`, it contains the following (numerous API keys removed):

```
EnvironmentConfigurationMetadata:
  Description: Includes API keys for live operation
  DateModified: '1437734273000'
  DateCreated: '1437734273000'
AWSConfigurationTemplateVersion: 1.1.0.0
EnvironmentTier:
  Name: WebServer
  Type: Standard
SolutionStack: 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.3 running Python 2.7
OptionSettings:
  aws:elb:loadbalancer:
    CrossZone: true
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:command:
    BatchSize: '30'
    BatchSizeType: Percentage
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    IamInstanceProfile: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
    EC2KeyName: aws-eb
    InstanceType: t2.micro
  aws:elb:policies:
    ConnectionDrainingEnabled: true
  aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate:
    RollingUpdateType: Health
    RollingUpdateEnabled: true
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DATA_DIR: /opt/python/current/app/data
    WSGIPath: /opt/python/current/aws_wsgi.py
  aws:elb:healthcheck:
    Interval: '30'
```

(NB. The WSGIPath environment variable there is invalid - but I am unable to remove it from the configuration due to bugs in the AWS Dashboard. It appears to have no effect anyway.)

How do I get AWS to respect my chosen WSGIPath?

Comment: How are you deploying your code? Are you using the CLI or the console?

Comment: Also, as a note the saved configuration overrides only the values you set. So if you have a, b ,c in ebextensions, and you put a in your saved configuration, then b and c will NOT get overridden

Comment: I deploy via `eb create` - question edited to show this.

Comment: Can you show the contents of `Live` (edit sensitive information) and the contents of `eb create --verbose`?

Comment: Have updated to show the config, after wasting some time trying to remove the redundant environment variable via the Dashboard (which only lets me add things, not remove them, and isn't clear on which changes it will save in the configuration and which ones it won't)

Comment: As for `eb create --verbose`, I saw nothing in there that wasn't in the non-verbose output apart from a couple of lines at the start about using project code and getting the version label from git.

Comment: Yep, that's the part I wanted to see. Also wanted to check and make sure the .config file was actually getting uploaded.

Comment: You'll probably need a new commit to get the file upload output, as otherwise it won't upload anything.

Comment: I added a comment to the config file in question, committed it, watched `eb create` gather and upload everything including that file, and the result is the same. It runs application.py, makes no attempt to use aws_wsgi.py. Dashboard shows application.py and offers no way to change it.

Comment: Weird. I did everything to the letter as you stated here, and could not reproduce. I am able to change the wsgi path. (it doesnt work because you should be using the relative path, but thats a different issue). As long as the .ebextension is being uploaded, it should work. I would really like to see the lines where it shows it is being upload as stated in your above comment.

Comment: I added the start of the log file. Today I will probably work on trying to create a minimal example of this.

Comment: So one slightly related problem is that your wsgi path should just be `aws-wsgi.py`, not the full path. But that won't fix your current issue, just your next one.

Comment: I tried using no saved configuration to see if it makes a difference, but it still insists on using application.py, so I've ruled that out. It even applies another option_settings value correctly from the same file containing the WSGIPath, so the file is being handled, just that one setting is ignored. (I corrected it to the relative path, but why would that make a difference in future?)

Comment: I'm wondering if you have some other ebextension  that is set to application.py and is being executed second, and overriding the previous extension. As far as relative path, it just needs to be that way, due to how internals work.

Comment: I have 5 short .config files, and the only one that mentions WSGIPath is the one shown above. The only reference to 'application.py' anywhere is in the dashboard.